# Load Parse.File url into EJS template

Tags: javascript, express, parse-platform, ejs

I'm trying to rendering out an html template using EJS, Express and Parse.com. Basically whenever I try to reference a Parse.Files url() call from within my EJS template it errors and nothing gets returned. These images are hosted on Parses cloud, not in the public directory.

```
    <div class="reviews">
        <% reviews.forEach(function(review,index) { %>
            <div class="review">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <h3><a href="#user/"><img class="profile-img" src="<%= review.get('createdBy').get('pictureThumbnail').url() %>" width="35" height="35"/>Test</a></h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        <% }) %>
</div>
```

I've run a console.log() on review.get('createdBy').get('pictureThumbnail').url() and I get back a simple url string. But if I put it in the template I get nothing.
I've tried using <%- <%= <%, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the issue was that I wasn't checking to make sure that the file actually existed and there were two items that had no images associated with them, this was causing the whole thing to error, but since I wasn't getting an error in the terminal I really had no idea what was happening.

So lesson learned, always make sure you are checking for empty objects in EJS.